# Inheriting Permissions for New Files

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, access-control-list, ext4

I'm having trouble getting inherited permissions to work on an ext4 filesystem. In `fstab` I added the `acl` attribute, and when I try the following I expect the new files to get `rwxrwx---` permissions, but I don't understand how the test files get the resulting `rw-r--r--` permissions.

```
louis@hartlab:/$ sudo mkdir /test
louis@hartlab:/$ sudo chmod 2770 test
louis@hartlab:/$ sudo chown louis:hartusers /test
louis@hartlab:/$ sudo chmod g+s test
louis@hartlab:/$ cd test/
louis@hartlab:/test$ ls -lha
total 8.0K
drwxrws---  2 louis hartusers 4.0K Sep  9 01:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root  root      4.0K Sep  9 01:19 ..
louis@hartlab:/test$ touch test
louis@hartlab:/test$ ls -lha
total 8.0K
drwxrws---  2 louis hartusers 4.0K Sep  9 01:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root  root      4.0K Sep  9 01:19 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 louis hartusers    0 Sep  9 01:20 test


louis@hartlab:/test$ cd ..
louis@hartlab:/$ sudo chmod ug+rwx /test
slouis@hartlab:/$ sudo chmod o-rwx /test
louis@hartlab:/$ sudo chmod g+s /test/
louis@hartlab:/$ touch /test/test2
louis@hartlab:/$ ls -lha /test
total 8.0K
drwxrws---  2 louis hartusers 4.0K Sep  9 01:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root  root      4.0K Sep  9 01:19 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 louis hartusers    0 Sep  9 01:20 test
-rw-r--r--  1 louis hartusers    0 Sep  9 01:20 test2
```

What is a good way to start troubleshooting this?

Comment: It's working as intended. To define the permissions google `umask`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Heh, oops. Using umask I can get `660`, which is fine. Thanks. BTW, I was following this, which has a lot of upvotes: https://askubuntu.com/q/642236/39694

Comment: Well, this also states that this only sets the group ownership.

Comment: Oh, and you can remove the ACL attribute. You are not using it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yep, you're right again.